# obb files are deleted when updating the android application

Tags: android

After update the app, OBB files inside the ***Android/obb/packagename*** were deleted.Is there any way to stop this issue.

Comment: they shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, My application is in beta release in play store.Is Beta and Production release behave same. And FYI, I installed and updated the app using ADB. But In this scenario, the OBB files not deleted.

Comment: they should not be deleted in any case. Beta and production should not have any difference

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I am trying to update my application in play store and  I observed that update size of app is equals to total size of app. Here I don't know why my application doesn't support delta update. FYI, I developed the app using Eclipse.

Comment: in general, Eclipse should not matter too, but *probably* it does not support something in Android SDK that is not compatible with delta update. Or also there is a chance that you implemented delta update incorrectly